# Azure Data Factory - Trigger data transformation from one table to another table in different format

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory (ADF), is it possible to setup database trigger in one ADF database table? So, if there is any data inserted into that one ADF database table, I could trigger SQL to transform the data and insert it into another ADF database table in different format.

Please advise. Thanks.

Thank you,

Hatjhie

Comment: By _ADF database table_ do you mean a database table that ADF knows about? Are these two tables in the same database? The same server? The same database platform?

Comment: Do you think about use logic app triggers?

Comment: Thanks. It is in the same database platform. We just want to transform the data. So table A received data from CSV. Then we want to create database table trigger in table A, to transform data in certain way to insert into table B.

Comment: About logic app triggers, how do we trigger it? By comparing the previous records?

Comment: Hi @Hatjhie, Logic app has the SQL trigger when a item is modified, then add an action get a pipeline run to run the Data Factory pipeline(copy the data from one table to another). It's also very easier.

Comment: Hi @Hatjhie, Is that feed your request?

Comment: Thanks Leon. I am currently searching through the possibility to use Azure Data Factory to trigger functions app. So, when the data received in table A, the function app will be trigger then it will transform data from table A to table B. 

So, with this, we do not need to maintain schedule for function app. Does this approach possible? Thanks.

Comment: It seems possible through here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity

Comment: _It is in the same database platform_. Then just write a stored procedure to do it and trigger it from ADF. Using Azure functions to do something that can be simply and efficiently done in a database is the wrong approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ADF supports three types of triggers : Schedule trigger, Tumbling window trigger and Event-based trigger. Event-based trigger contains Storage event trigger and Custom event trigger. There is no trigger for inserting or updating to Database in ADF by now. You can vote [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/39508147-df-event-trigger-on-update-or-insert-within-azur) to progress this feature.

Comment: Thanks Steve for your information. So if that's the case, we probably need to have function app to check and transform accordingly?

Comment: No you are completely overcomplicating it. If the source and target tables are in the same database, just write a stored procedure in the database that does the work and trigger it from ADF (or anything).